# How should I fill gaps between floorboards?

Tags: floor, gap

We have a Girl Scout camp and I'm the new property manager. We have cabins that are on stilt-like legs, approximately 20 years old. The flooring in these cabins has large gaps in between each piece of wood plank; lots of debris gets in these cracks (a pencil fits nicely inside the cracks).

There are three cabins that need the gaps filled; what is the best solution to fill them?

Comment: The *best* solution is to pull-up and re-lay the flooring. For certain values of *best*. Otherwise you can lay new flooring over the old.

Answer (score 2):

I'll both disagree and agree with @RedGrittyBrick's comment. The  best solution is to treat the existing floor as a subfloor and lay a tight new floor over it at right angles or diagonally to the existing boards.

Pulling up an existing floor is almost never the best (especially when cost is an object, and it usually is) solution unless it's rotten.

Comment: It's difficult to say this for sure, without seeing the condition of the floor. Pulling up the floor *might* be the *best* option, if the current floor is in poor shape.

Comment: Given the described problem with the existing floor (large gaps, perhaps 1/4-3/8") not rot or being horribly out of plane, it's not so hard to say for sure, sight unseen, IMHO. I've worked in plenty of old new england houses that were floored with wide green boards, that shank and created much larger gaps than described, which were perfectly fine subfloors for the floors laid over them.